# Where is sound output on openjdk gervill software mixer

Tags: java, audio, gervill

I was looking at the gervill code as used in the openJDK, because I wanted a mixer that is not directly dependent on any external libraries. I guessed that the mixer outputs raw audio data somewhere that can be send to actual sound hardware or something else, but however hard I look I cannot find the place where the sound/samples is supposed to get out. Is it in the softmixingmixer class or the sofmixingdatasourceline class I don't know. I can't find any documentation.

Anyone have any experience with this mixer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the openStream method in SoftSynthesizer to get the raw audio stream.

Take a look at Midi2WavRender to see how that is done:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130326054604/https://java.net/projects/gervill/sources/Mercurial/content/src.demos/Midi2WavRender.java?rev=289

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.